# Invalid left hand assignment

Tags: javascript

Could someone please explain why following code throws `Invalid left hand assignment` error on `this = evt.target;`

```
 validateNumber: function( evt ) {

        this = evt.target;

         if (/\D/g.test(el.value)) {
            // Filter non-digits from input value.
            el.value = el.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
         }
    },
```

**Update**

I was using `this` instead `el` before. It works fine after replacing `this` to `el`.

Comment: You can't assign `this`. You have to use `.apply`, `.call` or `.bind` to change the context of the function.

Comment: as far as i know, you can't reassign `this`

Comment: It might help if you could explain *why* you want to assign a value to `this`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't assign to `this` directly. It's simply not allowed.

There's no code in your question that *uses* `this`, so I'm not sure what you're up to, but if you wanted to force `this` to be a value you could do something like:

```
  (function() {
    if (/\D/.test(el.value)) {
      // ...
    }
  }).call(evt.target);
```

That would ensure that `this` had the value of `evt.target` in the code inside that anonymous function. I can't think of any normal situation where it'd matter, because other than being unassignable `this` works just like any other variable. That is, something like

```
  var whatever = evt.target;
```

gives you something that's pretty much just as useful as `this` would be.

Comment: Thanks, I was using this instead of el before.

Comment: That would execute the function instantly, just like an IIFE, it would be better to use `bind`(or implement it if needed)

Comment: @LightStyle Yes, that's the intention. I was trying to give an example that'd result in a block of code running as if it were in-line, but with `this` forced to some value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign this. Use functions call or apply. For example, to invoke a method func using obj as the this pointer, do:

```
func.apply(obj, args);
```